# Why does my radio station not boost my dweller's charisma

Tags: fallout-shelter

So, I bought a radio room recently and its not boosting my dweller's charisma

Comment: Is there a reason you think it should? Last time I played, the radio studio attracted more dwellers and increased happiness. I can't find anything implying that this has changed.

Comment: The difference is that Charisma boosts the effectiveness of a dweller operating the radio room, it's not a training room. If you want to increase a dweller's charisma, you need to build and use a "Lounge" room.

Answer (score 4):

The Radio Studio isn't supposed to increase Charisma. It does two things:

- Attract more dwellers to your vault
- Increase the happiness of your dwellers.

It does not increase stats, and nothing anywhere implies it should. The room you may be looking for is the Lounge, which is unlocked with 40 dwellers and slowly increases the charisma of anyone placed in it.

Answer (score 0):

It only boosts happiness when played inside the vault. You can do that by turn it off from playing in the wasteland.